# Is There Anything Like Timer in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timer

Here is what I need -

```
def get_file_from_web()
    # This is a function which retries the following function when that function is not completed with in 1 min.
    timer(60)
    # This method is use to connect to internet and get the file specified and i should not take more than 1 min. 
    file = get_file()
end
```

Please help me to solve this problem guys. I need exactly a timer to trigger an action after the specified time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will try to get the file 3 times before failing.  The `get_file` method is wrapped in a `Timeout.timeout` block, which will raise a `Timeout::Error` if it takes longer than 60 seconds to complete. If the timeout error is raised we either retry the operation or re-raise the error depending on whether there are more retries left.

```
require 'timeout'

def get_file_from_web
  retries = 3
  begin
    Timeout.timeout(60) { get_file() }
  rescue Timeout::Error
    if (retries -= 1) > 0
      retry 
    else
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

You could also use the [retryable](https://github.com/nfedyashev/retryable) to reduce the amount of code needed.

```
require 'timeout'

def get_file_from_web
  Retryable.retryable(tries: 3, on: Timeout::Error) do
    Timeout.timeout(60) { get_file() }
  end
end
```